# Autowiring the actual property file in spring

Tags: java, spring

I know how to load property files in Spring and also how to use the vaules via autowiring.

I have now the problem of an external library (mailx) that wants a Properties object to be given to the Session. My question is simply how to autowire the complete Properties object for one specific properties file as class
e.g.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("mail.properties")
private Properties properties;
```

Is this possible in Spring or do I have to load the file by hand?

the external API uses this method definition that I want to satisfy

```
public static Session getInstance(Properties props)
```

I am using spring boot.

If something in my question is not clear please ask, so I can provide more info.

Comment: Try @PropertySources(value={@PropertySource("classpath:xxx.properties")})

Comment: You'll want to use property sources or a property configurator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit old so I guess you have found a way, but you can create a bean for a single .properties file like this:

```
@Log4j2
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:custom.properties", name = "custom-properties")
public class Config {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableEnvironment env;

    @Bean
    public Properties customProperties() {

        MutablePropertySources propertySources = env.getPropertySources();
        Properties props = (Properties) propertySources.get("custom-properties").getSource();

        // prints properties
        props.stringPropertyNames().forEach(name -> log.info(name + "=" + env.getProperty(name)));

        // prints unparsed expressions like ${random.value}
        props.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> log.info(e.getKey() + "=" + e.getValue()));

        // prints property source names
        propertySources.stream().forEach(log::info);

        return props;
    }
}
```

And Autowire it:

```
@Autowired
private Properties customProperties;
```